# user profile side menu and change content based on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have html menu in which user can click and then page change the content. it like user profile page in which user has list like account, billing, picture etc,

```
 <li><a href=""  data-box="index"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
 <li><a href=""  data-box="account"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit Profile</a></li>
 <div class="box index">
     @include("partials.profile_index") 
    </div>
  <div class="box account">
     @include("partials.profile_account") 
    </div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('a').click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    // hide everything
   $('.box').not(
       // except the corresponding box
       $('.box.'+$(this).data('box')+':hidden').fadeIn()
   ).fadeOut(); 
});

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up your code a little and added some comments for explanation.  This should work for you and also help with future debugging. Finally I also made sure that the incoming box animation occurs after the outgoing box has finished animating.  [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wzdmmL3b/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  // hide all boxes by default.
  $('.box').hide();

  // when someone clicks a link, process hiding/showing the correct box
  $('a').click(function(ev){

    // stop the default action for the click event.
    ev.preventDefault();

    // assign a friendly variable for the current box
    var currentBox = $(this).attr("data-box");

    // hide everything except for the box we want to show
    $('.box').not('.' + currentBox).fadeOut('slow', function() {

      // after the animation is complete fade in the box we want to show.
      $('.box.' + currentBox).fadeIn('slow');

    }); 

  });

});
```

Comment: still not working : i got the first one working : @include("partials.profile_index")  but the second one is not working :          @include("partials.profile_account") 
not sure why.... also when I click on other "a" href it also disapear

Comment: @Alzaabi98 Is your code still not working or is the fiddle not working?  The fiddle works for me on my browsers.  If it's your code that is still not working, can you please update your post with a fiddle of your current version so I can take a look?

Comment: your code is working fine.. only when I used it in my code.. it does not work

Comment: @Alzaabi98 please update your code (or create a fiddle) in your original question and I will try and help.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: "...click and then page change the content..." so I'm going to assume you want the browser to reload the page and not simply update the DOM via JavaScript.  Please excuse me if I misunderstood your question.

How I typically handle this is by assigning a URL variable named "action" to my links.  That way when the page reloads I know which content to display.

Your code may vary depending on what server-side language you're using. I'll demonstrate with CFML but the logic should be the same regardless of whether you're using PHP, etc.

Here's an example of how your links might look:

```
 <ul>
   <li><a href="index.cfm?action=myProfile" data-box="index"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.cfm?action=editProfile" data-box="account"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit Profile</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Then you would provide some type of server-side logic on the index.cfm page like this:

```
<!--- does the user want to view his/her profile? --->
<cfif action IS "myProfile">

    <div class="box index">
      @include("partials.profile_index") 
    </div>

</cfif>

<!--- does the user want to edit his/her profile? --->
<cfif action IS "editProfile">

    <div class="box index">
      @include("partials.profile_account")
    </div>

</cfif>
```

With this solution you don't need any of your JavaScript. Simply create normal links with URL variables which describe what you want your target page to display when it loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the way as below. Check demo - [Fiddle Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ermakovnikolay/jftdohj4/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').click(function(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();

        // hide everything
        var $thisBox = $('.box.' + $(this).data('box') );
        $('.box').not( $thisBox ).fadeOut();
        if ( $thisBox.is(':hidden') ) {
            $thisBox.fadeIn();
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: only first link working .. sceond is not working.. also all "a" clicked are impacted which I dont want

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about. In the demo from my answer both links work fine.

Comment: i am stuck.. I looking for profile buttons in the left and content in the right.. the content should bring data from server.. for example.. account info.. photo... billing info .. ect... i am using laravel as lang.